# There is an Firebage Storage Plugin Error on my Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, firebase, plugins, cocoapods, firebase-storage

In my flutter application, when I send an image to firebase on IOS emulator, I get an error which is: "The 'plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel." But I'm not getting that error in Android emulator. I informed my coworker, so we tried to execute this application on IOS emulator of M2 Macbook Air again and it worked. But my M1 Macbook Air is always getting this error.

I tried flutter clean
flutter run but it didnt work.

pod deintegrate and pod install didnt work too.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJxcC.png)

Answer (score 1):

After updating Flutter, when I uploaded a file to Firebase Storage from iOS Simulator (M1 Macbook Pro), I met the same error: firebase_storage says the problem is a message sent from native to Flutter in a non-platform thread. It says to refer to the documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#architecture, so I read it, but there's nothing special to do in the Flutter app, and it looks like the plugin needs to be modified.

I tried several things,
After restarting the iOS Simulator, I got the Platform Channel Error Message, but the file went to Storage fine and the rest of the code worked fine. lol

Answer (score 0):

This is just my case, but I couldn't get it with AssetEntity.title on iOS (I could get it with Android), so I changed it to await AssetEntity.titleAsync and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).